# How to parse and show hyperlinks (phone number/email addresses etc) in UILabel?

Tags: iphone

Almost everywhere in the iPhone, you can type text and the OS will recognize portion of the text to be hyperlinks (phone numbers, email addresses for example). However I tested this in my own app with a UILabel and it doesn't work. How do I activate this?

Does the iphone sdk provide this functionality out of the box or do I have to do the parsing logic myself (which is a lot of work)?

Comment: I think the UILabel is a pretty primitive class - it pretty much just displays text with certain fonts applied. Maybe try a UITextField?

Comment: No, just tested it, UITextField doesn't parse it either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use UITextView as follows:

```
UITextView *myView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
myView.text = @"this is http://google.com link";
myView.editable = NO;
myView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
//cell is the TableView's cell    
[cell.contentView addSubview:myView];
[myView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out Styled Labels under the [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) project.

Comment: From what I can see in the source, that presents text with different styles but does nothing about presenting links.

Comment: If you run the TTCatalog sample code, there's a section under "Styled Labels" that shows URLS automatically converted into live links. The styling can be controlled through CSS. It's much lighter weight than a UIWebView. 

Also, under "Table Cells" there's an external link cell that invokes an external URL.

Answer (score -3):

Give it a shot with a UIWebView.

Comment: Is it proper to have a lot of UIWebView in a single screen? This control will be duplicated many times in a tableView