# How do you create a hyperlink in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, hyperlink

How do you create a hyperlink in an iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also answered here in a similar SO question:
[How to parse and show hyperlinks (phone number/email addresses etc) in UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084664/how-to-parse-and-show-hyperlinks-phone-number-email-addresses-etc-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 1):

Where? Take a look at UITextView's dataDetectorTypes property. Specifically UIDataDetectorTypeLink or UIDataDetectorTypeAll.